# Seeing objects in WebStorm console from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

WebStorm allows me to highlight my mouse over an object in code and inspect it like so :

[image]

Is it possible to do this from the console as well, the way google web tools does it?

In the console all I get is this disappointing output when I type in my object (`findObj`) :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can either use `JSON.stringify` :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(yourObject, null, 4 /*for a proper indentation*/));
```

or use the `inspect` method of the `util` module :

```
const util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(util, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));
```

https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options

Comment: You rock bro. Just a small edit to those of whom it's not obvious: console.log(util.inspect(yourObject, { showHidden: true, depth: null }));

Answer (score 2):

To inspect objects/arrays evaluated in debugger console, you need to mouse hover over the result or hit `Alt+Ctrl+F8` (**Quick Evaluate Expression**).

[image]

To have results represented as a tree view in console, please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14856